# Apollo Federation 2 displaying query plan in apollo studio while using it as embedded

Tags: apollo, apollo-federation

Using federation 2. I'd like to use Apollo Explorer as a landing page by setting;
`ApolloServerPluginLandingPageLocalDefault({ embed: true })`. Works nicely.

However, couldn't get query plan;

[image]

Any chance to get the query plan in Apollo Explorer while using it as embedded?